# Почему RLIKE не находит строку в Mysqli?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli, select, search

Мой запрос должен найти строку с формулой (столбец строкового типа) "z=x+iy", но почему-то возвращает ноль, что можно сделать?

```
SELECT * FROM `book_material` WHERE Content RLIKE "[[:<:]]z=x+iy[[:>:]]"
```

Comment: Ну например потому, что вы знак `+` не экранируете и он означает "много букв 'x'" (так оно в кавычках требуются 2 обратные косые)

Comment: @Mike а есть функция экранирования?

Comment: зачем функция, вы же руками регулярку пишите и экранирование это часть синтаксиса регулярных выражений `"[[:<:]]z=x\\+iy[[:>:]]"`  никакая функция не поймет что вы имели под знаком `+` "много символов" или собственно сам знак +

Comment: @Mike спасибо :)